# Value of the sum: $\binom{19}{0} - 1/2\binom{19}{1} +1/3\binom{19}{2} - 1/4\binom{19}{3} ...... -1/20\binom{19}{19}$?

Tags: summation

How do I find the value of this sum? I tried taking out the equal binomial coefficients as factors but this didn't really simplify anything. I am stumped.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{k+1} = \int_0^1 t^k dt$

Comment: I am supposed to work this out without calculus, I sadly don't know what that would even mean.

Comment: Calculus way:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{19} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\binom{19}{k} = \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{19} \binom{19}{k} (-t)^k dt = \int_0^1 (1-t)^{19} dt = \frac{1}{20}$$
If you are not allowed to use calculus, you should state that in your question.

Comment: Will pay attention to that next time. Appreciated anyhow :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe $$\frac{1}{k} {{n-1}\choose k-1}=\frac{1}{k}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{n(n-1)!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{1}{n}{n\choose k}$$
The sum you are looking for is equal, according to binomial theorem, to $$\frac{1}{20}\sum_{k=1}^{20}(1)^{20-k}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}{20\choose k}=\frac{1}{20}\left[1-\sum_{k=0}^{20}(1)^{20-k}\left(-1\right)^k{20\choose k}\right]=\frac{1}{20}\left[1-(1-1)^{20}\right]=\frac{1}{20}$$

Comment: Equal to? Not quite!

Comment: @SimonS: Thanks, I had a fault.

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k+1)!}=\frac1{n+1}{n+1\choose k+1}$$